# How to show responsive adsense ads only on mobiles devices

Tags: css, mobile, desktop, adsense

I am looking for a correct implementation method to display/hide my adsense ads on mobile and desktops.

Right now I am using this current method which gives us 2 console errors.

The current method is:

We use 2 classes "mobileShow" and "mobileno" to tag the ads accordingly to where we want to show them.

So if we want the responsive adsense code to be shown on mobiles we use mobileshow if we want to hide the big rectangular ads from mobiles we use mobileno.

The code we are using is the following:

```
.mobileShow {display: none;}
.mobileShow {display: inline;}
   @media only screen
   and (min-device-width : 320px)
   and (max-device-width : 480px)

.mobileno{display:none;}
   @media (max-width: 767px)
```

As far as we know google adsense policy allows display:none if it is for a usage like implementing responsive layouts.

Our problem is the we receive the following error 2 times in the chrome development console:

2 x **Uncaught Error: Cannot find a responsive size for a container of width=0px and data-ad-format=auto adsbygoogle.js:41**

We have tested several times we know that is something wrong with the above code.

We are looking a way to implement the current "solution" with no errors.

We would be very grateful if someone helps us out.

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, adsense gives the publisher two choice; responsive and custom and responsive works pretty on mobile without handling the customization (although adsense permit it).

Comment: Our mobile implementation of adsense achieves better profits that way

Comment: perhaps what Cannot find a responsive size for a container of width=0px means that the format you inserted was not supported by Adsense. what is your mobile measurement?

Comment: What do you mean by mobile measurement? I declare the size of screen via the css above.

Comment: adsense has certain ads sizes (ads size format = measurement, sorry), right? and a custom and a responsive. I usually use responsive ads format to handle this and everything is okay when I try it in mobile or tablet. So, I don't need to custom.

Answer (score 0):

I was also unsatisfied with the outcome of completely automatic ad sizes and after a split test I found setting specific sizes for the responsive ads more helpful without losing on performance.

AdSense gave an example and I just tweaked it with your data.

```
<style type="text/css">
.adslot_1 { display: none; }
@media (min-width:320px) { .adslot_1 { width: 320px; height: 50px; } }
@media (min-width:480px) { .adslot_1 { display: none; } }
</style>
<ins class="adsbygoogle adslot_1"
    style="display:inline-block;"
    data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234"
    data-ad-slot="5678"></ins>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful information for future readers:

`Cannot find a responsive size for a container of width=0px and data-ad-format=auto` is an error I get from responsive AdSense ads when I have AdBlock Plus **disabled on the current site**, but not **disabled everywhere**.

As soon as I check "Disabled everywhere", the AdSense error stops showing up, and responsive AdSense ads show correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code might be right but a little change could be needed.
By changing

`and (min-device-width : 320px)`

`and (max-device-width : 480px)`

to

```
and (min-width : 320px)
and (max-width : 480px)
```